No expected reply to a message from a Discord test server, using Discord Intents in Python
I know that the Python script (3.12) is connecting to the Discord server from the following response in the PyCharm terminal
[2024-08-13 00:55:09] [INFO    ] discord.client: logging in using static token
[2024-08-13 00:55:09] [INFO    ] discord.gateway: Shard ID None has connected to Gateway (Session ID: xxxx).
Logged on as D&D Random Room Generator#9850!
However, when I type "$hello" as a user in the Discord server,I expect a response of "Hello World" on the Discord server, but get no reply of any kind. There is no error code either. Is there something wrong with my code, or is this some kind of permissions problem with the bot role on the Discord server?
import discord


intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as {0}!'.format(self.user))


client = MyClient(intents=intents)

async def on_message(self, message):
  if message.author == self.user:
    return

  if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
    await message.channel.send('Hello World!')


client.run('My Token')



"Nothing happens" is not a question: Please [edit] your question to specifically and clearly define the problem that you are trying to solve. Additional details — including all relevant code, error messages, and debugging logs — will help readers to better understand your problem and [what you are asking].

Maybe it's not working because you didn't add the decorator to on_message?

Thanks Lia. That appears to be working, with the changes you made.

When using on_message function outside of Client class, you need a @client.event decorator.
In your case it would be easier to move on_message inside the class, seeing you already have self as an argument.
class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as {0}!'.format(self.user))

    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.author == self.user:
            return

        if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
            await message.channel.send('Hello World!')


client = MyClient(intents=intents)

